# Hashmap is empty on GWT async callback

Tags: java, gwt

Server side, I construct a java.util.Hashmap, populate it with values (key and value are both String) and pass it back to the client via an async callback. It is empty when it gets back to the client side.

I can replicate this with a net new hashmap that is only used in one place server side. Java 6 and GWT 2.7

**Server side service:**

```
public class Service extends RemoteServiceServlet implements IService {

    public Model buildModel() {
     Model model = new Model();
     model.addItemToMyMap("key", "value");
     return model;
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
 public class Model implements Serializable {

            private Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            public void addItemToMyMap(String key, String value) {
              if(key != null) {
                 myMap.put(key, value);
             }
            }
            public Map<String, String> getMyMap() {
                return myMap;
            }
       }
```

**Async Interface:**

```
public interface IServiceAsync {

 public void buildModel(AsyncCallback<Model> callback); {
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
    service.buildModel(new AsyncCallback<Model>() {
       public void onSuccess(Model model) {
        logger.warning(model.getMyMap().size());
    }
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
       logger.warning("ERROR!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Im not 100% on this but I'm pretty sure your `Model` needs to implement the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: My bad,  it does,  i just forgot to include it. Other primitive and string properties are fine.

Comment: You meant the `Model` class should implement the `IsSerializable` interface, did you?

Comment: GWT supports Serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Eclipse save actions was making the map final and thus preventing serialization. When I removed the final modifier (and prevented Eclipse from adding it back), I was able to see the map's contents on the client side.